# RecyclerView android: Getting an item at a particular position

Tags: android, android-listview, android-recyclerview

Is there any way to get an item of the RecyclerView at a particular position outside the adapter. e.g in ListView we could do:

```
    listView.getItem(position);
```

Can we do this with RecyclerView ? and also is the order of provided data list maintained ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add your own method to `RecyclerView` or I would suggest the `RecyclerView.Adapter` itself.

For instance, for ListView, you have:

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return listData.get(position);
}
```

You can add the same thing to your `RecylcerView.Adapter` or access it another way by adding a simple method to your `RecylcerView.Adapter`:

```
public List<Model> getList() {
    return this.mModel;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
recyclerView.getAdapter().getList().get(position)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had this method in the adapter but i couldn't access it. I tried casting recyclerView.getAdapter() to my adapter class and now i can access it.

Comment: I would argue that if you do this, you expose the list with a possibility of it getting modified from outside. A better way would be to only expose the element according to the ID like so:
`return this.mModel.get(id)`