# RecyclerView.Adapter get item position of my list

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have created a `RecyclerView.Adapter` and I want to fill a list.. so my problem now is I don't know how to implement the get position of my list.

below you can see my code:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    List<Result> _contents;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<Result> contents) {
        this._contents = contents;
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return _contents.size();
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int position) {
        View view = null;
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_item_card_small, parent, false);

        Result tempResult = _contents.get(position);

        TextView temp = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_city_name);
        temp.setText(tempResult.getInfo().getCity().getName());

        return new RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        };
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

       }
    }
```

so the function `onCreateViewHolder` doesn't get properly the id is always the same id.. how can I fix this or implement to get the right position of mi list?¿ What it´s happening now is the list has the right number of items but is always the same item, the fist one. I guess it´s something simple but I cant figure out how to implement it.

Thanks!!

Comment: So you changed `viewType` to `position` and expected it to now hold a position?

Comment: Well the position is always the same but it's because I dont know how to implement it. _contents is my list of items so.. How can I get the position there to fill the proper item in my view? Do u know what I mean? @karaokyo

Comment: The method signature is: `onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)`. `onCreateViewHolder` will not have a position. You are suppose to populate the view in `onBindViewHolder`. Please check the tutorial and report back if you have any problems: https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RecyclerView android: Getting an item at a particular position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28037480/recyclerview-android-getting-an-item-at-a-particular-position)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have fixed the issue implementing my own ViewHolder, I was a little bit confused. Below is the code working properly.

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    List<Result> _contents;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<Result> contents) {
        this._contents = contents;
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return _contents.size();
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = null;
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_item_card_small, parent, false);
        return new RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Result tempResult = _contents.get(position);
        holder.mTextView.setText(tempResult.getInfo().getCity().getName());
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView mTextView;
        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            mTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_city_name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you confused about?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you need the position of your list. You can get the position in **onBindViewHolder**. However, you can put any data you inside ViewHolder and use them later on.

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ResultViewHolder> {
    List<Result> _contents;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<Result> contents) {
        this._contents = contents;
    }

    public Result getItem(int position) {
        return _contents != null ? _contents.get(position) : null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return _contents.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public ResultViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_item_card_small, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ResultViewHolder holder, int position;) {
        Result result = getItem(position);
        holder.position = position;
        holder.result = result;
        holder.cityName.setText(result.getInfo().getCity().getName());
    }

    public static class ResultViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements
            View.OnClickListener {
        int position = -1;
        Result result;
        TextView cityName;

        public ResultViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            cityName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_city_name);
            view.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // do whatever you want with list posisiton and result...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

onBindViewHolder method recieves position as second argument. you can manipulate your view in this method.

```
package com.virgooll.avaa.shop.views;


import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.virgooll.avaa.R;
import com.virgooll.avaa.detailedIndex.model.StoreItem;

import java.util.List;

public class MasonryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MasonryAdapter.StoreItemViewHolder> {
List<StoreItem> items;
int itemsIndex;

public MasonryAdapter(List<StoreItem> items) {
    this.items = items;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public MasonryAdapter.StoreItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    itemsIndex = i;
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.detailed_index_list_item, viewGroup, false);
    MasonryAdapter.StoreItemViewHolder pvh = new MasonryAdapter.StoreItemViewHolder(v);
    return pvh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MasonryAdapter.StoreItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.setImage(position);
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

public class StoreItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    StoreItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }

    public void setImage(int position) {
        ImageView image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.detailed_index_fragment_inner_list_view_image);
        image.setImageResource(items.get(position).photoId);
    }
}
}
```